# SQL Server 2012 Job Failure After Installation of TTU16 ODBC Drivers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, odbc, teradata

On my developer machine, I have installed `Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.10`, as well as its ICU Libraries and GSS Client dependencies.

I have a SQL Server (2012) job that executes an SSIS package that connects to Teradata dwh via an ADO.NET connection manager. After installation of the driver, the job is now failing seconds after beginning runtime with the following message:

> ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection
>   {0E566FAB-D3B4-496D-99CE-667747B8E83F} with the following error
>   message: "ERROR [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Loading the
>   Teradata ICU Library Failed. Error is: 126  ERROR [01000] The driver
>   returned invalid (or failed to return) SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER: 03.80 
>   ERROR [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Loading the Teradata
>   ICU Library Failed. Error is: 126".  End Error

I have installed both 32 bit and 64 bit drivers. The underlying ssis package executes successfully in Visual Studio 2010.

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Kind of sounds like a bad installation. Are you able to test by creating your own DSN on the machine and attempting a connection through it (or use Test Connection during the DSN set up in ODBC Administrator)?

Comment: I am able to connect to a test and to-be-used DSN via an ADO.NET Connection Manager in Visual Studio 2010. I can also establish a connection via tdxodbc.exe from the Teradata bin folders (both 32 and 64 bit)

Comment: So it's not an ICU issue, or an ODBC install issue, and it's not a platform/32-bit/64-bit issue. I'm wondering then if your Teradata library in your `ado.net` project is a different version than the driver. [There is some talk here at the end of the convo](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/215d6fda-62ae-482b-8a97-c3594142eba5/ado-net-source-has-failed-to-acquire-the-connection-with-the-following-error-message-could-not?forum=sqlintegrationservices) related to that.

Comment: Thanks for the additional resource. The underlying SSIS package needs (and is set to) run in 32 bit runtime in SQL Server as it uses features only compatible with 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the server fixed the issue on my developer machine.

Using the Repair executable provided by Teradata also seemed to fix the issue. I'm guessing the old driver was in use so references to it were still kept even after installation, and rebooting the server reconfigured this.